# FullCalendar event editable callback

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

I am implementing a FullCalendar Scheduler where the client can drag the events around the timeline.

When an event is dragged and dropped somewhere, an ajax call is made, where the backend perform some operations on the database, and possibly reverts the event if something went wrong.

What I want to achieve, is to block the event dragging possibility, while the backend script runs, so the users can not drag and drop anything until the backend code finishes. This could be easily achievable, by having a callback function for the event objects `editable` property where I check a global variable to determine if any event is in the upgrading process currently, or not, but unfortunatly, it seems that FullCalendar does not support this.

Do you know of any other solution to achieve my desired behaviour?

At the moment I am using `FullCalendar V3`, so I would prefer a solution to that version, but if an easy to implement solution shows itself with `V4`, I am willing to upgrade.

Comment: Here's an idea: before you start the ajax call, set the editable option to `false` in fullCalendar. When the ajax completes, set it `true` again. You can set options using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/dynamic-options. Why do you need to do this though? Can't your server handle multiple requests?

Comment: The per event `editable` overwrites the global `editable` property, so I could only do this, by fetching all currently visible events, and rerendering them all, which I would want to avoid. For why I want to do this, is because: when I perform actions with the calendar events, and those actions get rejected by the server, the calendar should revert the event back to it's original position. If I do this very quickly, somehow, some of the events do not get placed back in their original position.

Comment: Good point about the per-event property. So some of your events are not editable? Or could you just set it globally? Also, perhaps you could show us exactly how you are doing the action with the event and combining with the action to the server, and how you handle the rejection and try to revert the event's position? Maybe we can fix that for you instead.

Comment: #ADyson that code would be a novel, I don't think anyone would read through it:) And yes, unfortunately, there are some events that are always disabled from editing, and all events should be disabled, while the back-end code operates, and then reverted back to their original status.